# Override existing class by a class loaded through java class loader

Tags: java, class, java-8, classloader

I have a class called MyTest in my package. It has a method called `int getVal()`. I want this class to be over ridden by a class with the same name in a jar (say `abc.jar`). I am loading the jar using java class loaders but still I am not able to override the class in my package. I don't want to use reflection. Is there any way to override the package class by a class in jar?

I also tried `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(myclassloader)`.

Comment: Try to check the text of tags before you use them for questions. `JCL` is not what you wanted, but the one you want may already be out there.

Comment: As it looks like you are trying to do this for a test, have you considered using a mocking framework like Mockito or PowerMock instead? What you are trying to do seems to be really dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `abc.jar` appears first in the class path.

Adding another class loader will probably not work when classes depending on `MyTest` are loaded by a different class loader.

Comment: Is there any other way other than class loaders ? I have to over ride the method in my package by loading a class from the jar.

Comment: As I said, `abc.jar` must appear before your other classes in the class path.